# How to get value from var_dump as a single variable?

Tags: php, arrays, yii, var-dump

I hava a variable `$var->VerseTranslations` in yii framework. 
When i keep it in var_dump.

Like `var_dump($var->VerseTranslations);`

It gives an array which is in below.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(VerseTranslations)[96]
      private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
      private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'verse_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'language_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'translation_text' => string ' "In the name of ALLAH, most Gracious, most Compassionate". ' (length=60)
          'scholar_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(VerseTranslations)[97]
      private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
      private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '4' (length=1)
          'verse_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'language_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'translation_text' => string 'شروع الله کا نام لے کر جو بڑا مہربان نہایت رحم والا ہے' (length=96)
          'scholar_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(VerseTranslations)[98]
      private '_new' (CActiveRecord) => boolean false
      private '_attributes' (CActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '5' (length=1)
          'verse_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'language_id' => string '5' (length=1)
          'translation_text' => string 'En el nombre de Alá, el Compasivo, el Misericordioso' (length=53)
          'scholar_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Now i want to get first translation_text is in a single variable.
Like `$var->VerseTranslations->translation_text` but it gives error,I can get all the single variable using foreach loop but i do not want to use, i just need a single variable, so can you help me, how to get a single variable from an above array.

Thanks.

Comment: You should not try to _"get your value from `var_dump()`"_. Use original variable for that.

Comment: It's a combination of objects and arrays

Comment: `mydata` is array of objects. so you must use loop. or for fixed value `$var->mydata[0]->translation_text`

Comment: Something like `$var->mydata[0]->_attributes["translation_text"]` but you won't be able to access _attributes, since it is private. Maybe your VerseTranslation object has an accessor method for the translation_text

Comment: do not get result, giving an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single variable you can use it in given below.

```
$errors = array_filter($data->verseTranslations);
if(!empty($errors)) {
    echo $data->verseTranslations[0]['translation_text'];
}
```

You may also write this but i am using foreach loop too.

```
<?php $mydat = array();
 $errors = array_filter($data->verseTranslations);
 if(!empty($errors)) {
   foreach($data->verseTranslations as $var) 
     { $mydat[] = $var['translation_text'];  }
   echo $mydat[0];
}
?>
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using either print_r, or var_export

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php